# Countdown timer showing problem android

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I an new in android development.I have create an android application where i need to use a timer.
 I have took a text view  and a button . When my application is run the text view is set set 00:05:00 , When i tap on button then timer will be start and after five minute later the text view is set to "Done" how can i do that. plz help me .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Android CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) is the basic count down timer for android... Using that you can build this kind of [CountDownTimer](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.dimond.countdowntimer) by implementing the [date and time picker example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html)... You need to just integrate those two examples.

Answer (score 0):

use a `CountDownTimer`. There's numerous examples on this website and on the web.